# enabling the react-hooks eslint plugin in typescript. no plugins in tslint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tslint

Am I correct in saying that it is not possible to use [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) eslint plugin with tslint?

I tried adding this to my tslint.json:

```
"plugins": ["react-hooks"],
"rules: {
  "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
  "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
```

But I see the following errors in the console:

```
Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
    react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following library for nesting-react-hooks error.
https://github.com/Gelio/tslint-react-hooks
There is a PR pending from the same contributor in the core tslint repo. 
For the exhaustive deps rule which was introduced recently i have asked the author to add it into the same repo but still waiting for the response.
https://github.com/Gelio/tslint-react-hooks/issues/9